# I can't run gtg (getting things todo by gnome) properly

Tags: software-updater

I've installed gtg by adding ppa to repository. When I run gtg from terminal some features go idle. How can I active these features?

```
2013-05-05 17:27:15,934 - WARNING - __init__:__init__:77 - Backend backend_twitter could not be loaded: No module named tweepy.models
2013-05-05 17:27:15,937 - WARNING - __init__:__init__:77 - Backend backend_rtm could not be loaded: No module named dateutil.tz
2013-05-05 17:27:15,991 - WARNING - __init__:__init__:77 - Backend backend_evolution could not be loaded: No module named evolution
2013-05-05 17:27:15,991 - WARNING - __init__:__init__:77 - Backend backend_mantis could not be loaded: No module named suds.client
2013-05-05 17:27:15,992 - WARNING - __init__:__init__:77 - Backend backend_launchpad could not be loaded: No module named launchpadlib.launchpad
```

Answer (score 0):

GTG maintainer here. All those features are optional and provide you way how to synchronize with external services like Launchpad, Mantis or Evolution. Their dependencies are listed in [README](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~gtg/gtg/trunk/view/head:/README):

```
=== Dependencies for Synchronization Services ===

Evolution synchronization service has dependencies:
  * python-evolution
  * python-dateutil

Because of a bug in PyGTK (see https://bugs.launchpad.net/gtg/+bug/936183),
the synchronization service freezes GTG and the synchronization service can't be used.

MantisBT synchronization service has a dependency:
  * python-suds

Launchpad synchronization service has a dependency:
  * python-launchpadlib

Gnote and Tomboy synchronization services has no external dependency.

Identica and Twitter synchronization services are shipped with the local
version of Tweety library.

Remember the Milk synchronization service is shipped with a library for RTM api.
It has an external dependency:
  * python-dateutil

Remember the Milk is not maintained for a long time and might be potentially harmful.
```

As you can see, some of them are not mainted for a long time. We will be glad if somebody takes the ownership. Patches or any other contribution is welcome!

Additional features will be displayed when adding a new synchronization service in

> Edit -> Synchronization Services

Comment: too bad. I can't find appropriate todo app.